# How to rename multiple files by changing one component of the file name?

Tags: files, regular-expression, rename

I found lots of questions about how to rename multiple files using the command line. However I am not able to solve my specific issue which is renaming this file name:

```
something_4M_something_something_manyothersomethings.csv
```

into this:

```
something_4_M_something_something_manyothersomethings.csv
```

What I need is to split the `4M` field into `4_M` but I am not able to do it (notes: every *something* is separated by an underscore, there are many other fields, and I believe this is not important for the task).

What I did is the following but it does not work as I am expecting I think it is a problem with the regexp, but I can't figure out a better one:

```
rename -n 's/.4M/$&_4_M/' *
```

Also, I don't know how exactly the thing I wrote is working, since I found something similar in a comment to one of the similar-to-this-questions but I can't find it anymore.

Comment: Can you write a small program that can create the new filename given the old, that can be called for each file name?

Comment: Is it ensured that the pattern `4M` can only occur once in the filename, and is it also sure that you have the Perl-based `rename` tool (rather than the less powerful GNU `rename`)?

Comment: @AdminBee yep, it is exactly like that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, nope that is the issue :-). actually, yes maybe I can but it would be something hypercomplicated with lots of paste and cut and merge, and I prefer to keep it simple and learn something that was created for that specific goal, i.e. renaming.

Comment: In your situation I would write a small snippet in perl or awk that output the "mv X Y" command given X, and then create a large batch script using xargs.   Then inspect said script.  If ok, then run it.  Done.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, point is I don't know about perl and/or awk. I would do that using basic command such as `sed`, `cut` or `tr`...that is why I believe it would be super messy...

Comment: @gabt That is why I asked about whether you could write such a small program (in Python, whatever).  It appears that your rename is simple enough for a regular expression so that is good, otherwise the "generate a script, inspect it and then run it" is often handy.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen, yes, in this case I thought it would be easier enough. in more complex cases I think I can do some filename _management_. Thank you for your suggestion, though!

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen & gabt I have in the past, with no programming tools available, done this in spreadsheet cell formulae to build a (DOS/Win Batch) script, then exported the column of commands as a text file, renaming one file per line.  In that case we were re-ordering elements in the name, and moving into subfolders based on substrings in the name. Something similar could work here for a not-quite-programming approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If all you want to do is really replace `4M` by `4_M`, then a variant of your regexp does this:

```
$ ls
something_4M_something_something_manyothersomethings.csv
$ rename -n 's/4M/4_M/' *
'something_4M_something_something_manyothersomethings.csv' would be renamed to 'something_4_M_something_something_manyothersomethings.csv'
```

The regexp works on anything **inside** the name, so you don't need to do something specific to keep the leading "something".

If you want to do something else, like move the first "something" to the second "something", or restrict to the `4M` to the first occurance after an underscore, please edit your question and clarify.

---

As observed in the comments, `-n` does a dry-run, so it shows what would have happened, and doesn't actually perform the operation.

As the example in the question was already using `-n`, I was under the assumption that this was understood by the person asking.

Comment: this works great, in theory. However, it is not actually renaming but only printing the renamed filenames together with the old filenames. I am missing something here.

Comment: aha! apparently it is the `-n` option. So, no `-n`.

The final solution is: `rename 's/4M/4_M/' *`

Comment: @gabt Whenever I write an answer involving the perl `rename` utility, I add a paragraph explaining that `-n` makes it a dry-run, remove it ( or replace it with `-v` for verbose output) when you're sure it's going to do what you want.  I usually feel a little silly for repeating that every single time.   Your comment is *why* I do it, so I feel vindicated now :-)   It's completely obvious to those who already know it, but not at all obvious to those who don't.

Comment: @cas, yes, I think that adding such a piece of information is helpful for those who have no clue how to use the terminal. Luckily, I can read and understand the content of `man rename` :-)

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

For a single file:

```perl
    ~$ raku -e ' \
    my $name = dir(test => /^ something_4M_somethingelse \. csv $/)[0]; \
    my $modname = S/^ something_<(4M)>_somethingelse \. csv $/4_M/.IO given $name; \
    ($name,$modname).say; \
    #rename($name,$modname, createonly => True);'
```

For multiple files:

```perl
    ~$ raku -e ' \
    my @names = dir(test => /^ something_<digit><upper>_somethingelse \. csv $/); \
    my @modnames = do for @names {S/^ something_<(<digit><upper>)>_somethingelse \. csv $/$<digit>_$<upper>/.IO given $_;}; \
    for [Z] @names,@modnames -> ($x,$y) { ($x,$y).say }; \
    #for [Z] @names,@modnames -> ($x,$y) { rename($x,$y, createonly => True) };'
```

Directory Input:

```
~$ ls
something_4M_somethingelse.csv  something_5N_somethingelse.csv  something_6O_somethingelse.csv
```

Directory Output (multiple-file rename):

```
~$ ls
something_4_M_somethingelse.csv something_5_N_somethingelse.csv something_6_O_somethingelse.csv
```

CAVEAT: **Make backups first!!**

Brief explanation (single-file rename): obtain a `dir()` listing of a file-of-interest using the regex-matching ("adverb") option `test => / ... /`, and take only one element regardless (`[0]`), storing it in the scalar variable `$name`. Inspection of this variable shows it to be an `.IO` object.

Use the familiar `S///` idiom to modify the `given $name` variable, and store the modified name as `$modname`. Note here, `S///` stringifies so an `.IO` method call is added to the end of `S///` so that `$modname` is an `.IO` object as well.

Within the regex,  an unfamiliar symbol may be the `<(…)>` notation. But that's just Raku's ***capture markers***, so while the entire match in the left half of `S///` is recognized, only the `4M` match within `<(…)>` is captured, and modified in the right half of `S///`.

If the desired starting/ending `.IO` objects are obtained, the line `($name,$modname).say;` should produce output similar to the following:

```
("something_4M_somethingelse.csv".IO "something_4_M_somethingelse.csv".IO)
```

Once everything looks good, you can uncomment the last `rename()` line of the Raku code, to actually rename the files listed in the penultimate line with `.say`.

Note: Including the `createonly => True` adverb/option in the `rename()` code above means that `rename()` won't clobber an existing filename (the shorter form `:createonly` does the same thing). Remove the `createonly => True` or `:createonly` adverb/option to obtain the default (`False`, i.e. clobbering) and allow renaming-to (overwriting-of) a pre-existing file/filename.

https://docs.raku.org/syntax/S$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS$SOLIDUS
https://docs.raku.org/routine/rename
https://raku.org