# Renaming files in Linux using perl scripting

Tags: perl, rename, file-management

I have a set of files with prefix, say "pre_", on a Linux machine and I just want to rename all of these files by removing that. Here is the perl code I wrote it doesn't throw any errors, but the work is not done.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
my @files = `ls -1 | grep -i \"pre_.*\"`;
foreach $file ( @files )
{
  my @names = split(/pre_/, $file);
  my $var1 = $names[1];
  'mv "$file" "$var1"';
}
```

Comment: Debug. Print the old and new names just before the `mv`. My suspicion is that the grep pattern is wrong and returns no file names (maybe the backslashes are not wanted), but I don't do Perl. Or maybe the mv statement needs a keyword to actually execute it.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/730894/what-are-the-different-versions-of-the-rename-command-how-do-i-use-the-perl-ver/730895#730895

Comment: Why are there straight quote marks around the `mv` line?

Comment: Are you willing to consider an answer written in Raku (formerly Perl6)? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/676629/227738

Comment: Do you really want to rename the files to the part in between the first and second occurrence of `pre_` in their name? Why `-i` for `grep`, but no `i` flag in `/pre_/`. Do you or do you not want the match to be case insensitive?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You aren't executing anything. When you put something in single quotes (`''`), that's just a string, so `'mv "$file" "$var1"'` is not a command, it's a string and doesn't do anything. A string by itself is just a true statement. In order to execute the command, you need to use:

```
system "mv", "--", $file, $var1;
```

(**Not** <strike>`system("mv '$file' '$var1'")`</strike> which would introduce a command injection vulnerability).

But there's no need for that, `perl` has a `rename()` function, so you can do:

```
rename($file, $var1)
```

Next, you really shouldn't parse the output of `ls`, that is [a very bad idea and fragile](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It is also completely unnecessary in Perl (or any other programming language). If you want to match all files in the current directory containing the string `pre_` (which is what your `grep` does—you don't need the `grep`, by the way, you could have just used `ls -d -- *pre_*`), you can use `glob()` like this:

```
my @files = glob("*pre_*");
```

So, putting all that together, this is what you were trying to do:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use File::Glob qw(:globally :nocase);
my @files = glob("*pre_*");
foreach $file ( @files )
{
  my @names = split(/pre_/i, $file);
  rename($file, $names[1]);
}
```

But this isn't really a good idea. If you have two files with the same prefix (e.g. `pre_file1` and `apre_file1`), then the first file will be overwritten by the second file since, in this example, both files would be renamed to `file1` because your command would remove `pre_` and everything before it. So you can add a warning and skip those files:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use File::Glob qw(:globally :nocase);

my @files = glob("*pre_*");
foreach $file ( @files )
{
  my @names = split(/pre_/i, $file);
  if (-e $names[1]) {
    warn "Warning: Not renaming '$file' to '$names[1]' " .
        "because '$names[1]' exists.\n";
    next;
  }
  rename($file, $names[1]) or
    warn "rename '$file': $!\n";
}
```

---

Of course, all of this is reinventing the wheel. You can just install `perl-rename` (on Debian, Ubuntu, etc. run `apt install rename`, on other systems it might be called `prename` or `perl-rename`), and then you can do (although this is not case insensitive, it only finds files containing `pre_`):

```
rename -n 's/.*?pre_//si' ./*
```

The `-n` causes `rename` to just print what it would do, without actually renaming. Once you are sure the renaming works as expected, run the command again without the `-n` to actually rename the files.

Here the shell passes *all* (non-hidden) files to `rename` and `rename` will ignore the files whose name the `perl` code doesn't change. You could also tell the shell to only pass the file names that contain `pre_` case-insensitively with `./~(i)*pre_*` in `ksh93`, `./(#i)*pre_*` in `zsh -o extendedglob`, setting the `nocaseglob` option globally in `bash`, `zsh` or `yash` or use `./*[pP][rR][eE]_*`.

Comment: Or `perl -e 'for (<*>) {if (/pre_(.*)/is) {rename $_, $1 or warn "rename $_: $!\n"}}'`. The OP seems to want to rename the file to the part after the first occurrence of `pre_` *case insensitively* in the file name.

Comment: Or `rename -n 's/.*?pre_//si' ./*pre_*` (also note the `./` prefix without which you introduce a command injection vulnerability).

Comment: Very good point about the `./` @StéphaneChazelas, thanks, added. And thanks for pointing out the `i`, I missed that in the OP. I made the script case insensitive now.

Comment: +1.   BTW, perl `rename`'s features are also available to custom perl scripts via the [File::Rename](https://metacpan.org/dist/File-Rename) module - in fact, the perl `rename` tool is itself an example of a perl script using that module.  I don't think the OP needs that here because they'd be better off just running `rename` from the shell.

Comment: @Raffa, ah yes, good point, I overlooked that. See edit.

Answer (score 8):

The tool you need already exists as `rename` (depending on your distro also `perl-rename` or `prename`)

```
rename 's/^pre_//' file1 file2 ...
```

Use `-n` for a dry run and `-v` for listing the renames.

Note: Not to be confused with the `rename` command from `util-linux` which works differently.

Answer (score 3):

... Other renaming alternatives as well (*rather than "reinventing the wheel"*) are ...

Using [`mmv`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/mmv.1.html) like so:

```bash
$ mmv -n '*_*.ext' '#2.ext'
pre_file_number1.ext -> file_number1.ext
pre_file_number2.ext -> file_number2.ext
pre_file_number3.ext -> file_number3.ext
pre_file_number4.ext -> file_number4.ext
```

Or in the Z Shell(*`zsh`*) using its builtin function [`zmv`](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) like so:

```bash
% autoload zmv
% zmv -n '*.ext' '${f#*_}' 
mv -- pre_file_number1.ext file_number1.ext
mv -- pre_file_number2.ext file_number2.ext
mv -- pre_file_number3.ext file_number3.ext
mv -- pre_file_number4.ext file_number4.ext
```

Notice: `-n` in both cases above is for a safe dry-run ... When satisfied with the output, remove it or substitute it with `-v`(*for verbosity*) so the actual renaming will happen.